# Как сделать фильтр изображений на ванильном js

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.введите сюда код Не могу разобраться каким образом можно сделать фильтр изображений по категориям из меню. Вот что я наковырял:

```
    section.portfolio 
     .portfolio__wrapper.container
        .portfolio__heading.heading_usual
            .heading__title.uppercase Portfolio 
        .portfolio-menu.uppercase
            input(type="checkbox" checked, id="all", onclick="myFunction()")
            input(type="checkbox", id="entertainment", onclick="myFunction()")
            input(type="checkbox", id="sport", onclick="myFunction()")
            input(type="checkbox", id="business", onclick="myFunction()") 
            input(type="checkbox", id="building", onclick="myFunction()")
            label.portfolio-menu__item(for="all") all
            label.portfolio-menu__item(for="entertainment") entertainment  
            label.portfolio-menu__item(for="sport") sport
            label.portfolio-menu__item(for="business") business
            label.portfolio-menu__item(for="building") building
        .portfolio__content
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_big.sport.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_1.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase mountain bikes
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_small.building.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_2.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase Paints
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_small.entertainment.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_3.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase Bus
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_small.business.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_4.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase Boxes
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_small.business.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_5.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase Magazines
            .portfolio__item.portfolio__item_big.sport.all
                img.portfolio__image(src="./../../img/portfolio_6.jpg", alt="image")
                .invisible
                    .invisible__content.uppercase Cars
        .portfolio__button.button_m I want landing page
        .portfolio__scroll 
            .button-scroll_transparent
                svg.button-scroll__icon.icon
                    use(xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#arrow-down")

sass

    введите сюда код.portfolio  {
    padding: get_vw_size(80) 0 17px 0;
    text-align: center;

    &__heading {
        margin-bottom: 52px;
    }

    &__content {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 11px;
    }

    &__item {
        position: relative;
        display: none;

        &_big {
            grid-column: span 2;
            grid-row: span 1;

            @include scale(420) {
                grid-column: span 4;
                grid-row: span 1;
            }
        }

        &_small {
            grid-column: span 1;
            grid-row: span 1;

            @include scale(600) {
                grid-column: span 2;
                grid-row: span 1;
            }

            @include scale(420) {
                grid-column: span 4;
                grid-row: span 1;
            }
        }

        &:hover .invisible,
        &:hover .invisible__content {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    &__image {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 196px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }

    &__button {
        margin-top: 59px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    &-menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-content: stretch;
        padding: 20px 15px;
        border-top: 1px solid $subtitle_color;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $subtitle_color;
        margin-bottom: 46px;

        @include scale(768) {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }

        &__item {
            color: $decorate_color;

            &:not(:last-child):after {
                content: '/';
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: get_vw_size(65);
                padding-right: get_vw_size(65);
            }

            @include scale(768) {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
             }
        }

        &__input {
            color: $decorate_color;
        }
    }
}

.invisible,
.invisible__content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.invisible {
    background: $decorate_color;
    opacity: .78;

    &__content {
        padding: 25px 25px;
        text-align: left;
        font: get_rem(28px)/1 $encore_bold;
        color: #fff;

        &:before,
        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            height: 11px;
            width: 46px;
            background: #fff;
            top: 50%;
            right: 50%;
        }

        &:before {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        &:after {
            transform: translateX(50%) rotate(90deg);
        }
    }
}
```

js

```
function myFunction() {
var all = document.getElementById('all');
var entertainment = document.getElementById('entertainment');
var sport = document.getElementById('sport');
var business = document.getElementById('business');
var building = document.getElementById('building');

var allPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('all');
var entertainmentPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('entertainment');
var sportPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('sport');
var businessPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('business');
var buildPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('build');


if (all.checked == true) {
    allPhoto.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Comment: *сделать фильм изображений* - что это такое?

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка. Фильтр изображений.